# Retrieving tables located on metadata server with SAS

Tags: sas, metadata, sas-metadata

I want to list all tables on metadata server. I've tried with the following data step but it only pics one table per library and I can't figure out why.

This is the code I've been using:

```
options metaserver="xxxx"
    metaport=8561
    metauser="xxxx"
    metapass="xxxx"
    METAPROTOCOL=BRIDGE
    metarepository="Foundation";


data meta_libraries;
  length uri serveruri conn_uri domainuri libname ServerContext AuthDomain path_schema
         usingpkguri type tableuri coluri $256 id $17
         desc $200 libref engine $8 isDBMS $1 table colname coltype collen $32;
  keep libname desc libref engine ServerContext path_schema AuthDomain table colname coltype collen 
       IsPreassigned IsDBMSLibname id;
  nobj=.;
  n=1;
  uri='';
  serveruri='';
  conn_uri='';
  domainuri='';

         /***Determine how many libraries there are***/
  nobj=metadata_getnobj("omsobj:SASLibrary?@Id contains '.'",n,uri);
         /***Retrieve the attributes for all libraries, if there are any***/
  if n>0 then do n=1 to nobj;
     libname='';
     ServerContext='';
     AuthDomain='';
     desc='';
     libref='';
     engine='';
     isDBMS='';
     IsPreassigned='';
     IsDBMSLibname='';
     path_schema='';
     usingpkguri='';
     type='';
     id='';
     nobj=metadata_getnobj("omsobj:SASLibrary?@Id contains '.'",n,uri);
     rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "Name", libname);
     rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "Desc", desc);
     rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "Libref", libref);
     rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "Engine", engine);
     /*rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "IsDBMSLibname", isDBMS);*/
     rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "IsDBMSLibname", IsDBMSLibname); 
     rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "IsPreassigned", IsPreassigned); 
     rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "Id", Id);

        /*** Get associated ServerContext ***/
     i=1;
     rc= metadata_getnasn(uri, "DeployedComponents", i, serveruri);
     if rc > 0 then rc2= metadata_getattr(serveruri, "Name", ServerContext);
     else ServerContext='';

        /*** If the library is a DBMS library, get the Authentication Domain
             associated with the DBMS connection credentials ***/
     if isDBMS="1" then do;
        i=1; 
        rc= metadata_getnasn(uri, "LibraryConnection", i, conn_uri);
        if rc > 0 then do;
           rc2= metadata_getnasn(conn_uri, "Domain", i, domainuri);
           if rc2 > 0 then rc3= metadata_getattr(domainuri, "Name", AuthDomain);
        end;
     end;

        /*** Get the path/database schema for this library ***/
     rc=metadata_getnasn(uri, "UsingPackages", 1, usingpkguri);
     if rc>0 then do;
        rc=metadata_resolve(usingpkguri,type,id);  
        if type='Directory' then rc=metadata_getattr(usingpkguri, "DirectoryName", path_schema);
        else if type='DatabaseSchema' then rc=metadata_getattr(usingpkguri, "Name", path_schema);
        else path_schema="unknown";
     end;

       /*** Get the tables associated with this library ***/
         /*** If DBMS, tables are associated with DatabaseSchema ***/
     if type='DatabaseSchema' then do;
        t=1;
        ntab=metadata_getnasn(usingpkguri, "Tables", t, tableuri);
        if ntab>0 then do t=1 to ntab;
           tableuri='';
           table='';
           ntab=metadata_getnasn(usingpkguri, "Tables", t, tableuri);
           tabrc= metadata_getattr(tableuri, "Name", table);

                 output;
              end;
              else do;
               put 'Library ' libname ' has no tables registered';
               output;
              end;

        end;

     end;
     else if type='Directory' then do;
        t=1;
        ntab=metadata_getnasn(uri, "Tables", t, tableuri);
        if ntab>0 then do t=1 to ntab;
           tableuri='';
           table='';
           ntab=metadata_getnasn(uri, "Tables", t, tableuri);
           tabrc= metadata_getattr(tableuri, "Name", table);
            output;  
        end;
        else put 'Library ' libname ' has no tables registered'; 

  end;

      /***If there aren't any libraries, write a message to the log***/
  else put 'There are no libraries defined in this metadata repository.'; 
 run;
```

I've would appreciate if someone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use "proc metadata" instead of the data step functions.

This is a possible solution although it can be improved since it is bringing more information than it should.

```
options metaport       = &metaport
        metaserver     = "&metaserver"
        metarepository = "Foundation"
        metauser       = &meta_user.
        metapass       = "&meta_pass";


* use a temporary fileref to hold the request;
filename request temp;

* use a data step to create the XML request;
data _null_;
    file request;
    put '<GetMetadataObjects>';
    put ' <Reposid>$METAREPOSITORY</Reposid>';
    put ' <Type>PhysicalTable</Type>';
    put ' <Objects />';
    put ' <NS>SAS</NS>';
    * Flags: <!-- OMI_ALL(1) + OMI_GET_METADATA(256) + OMI_TEMPLATE (4)+ OMI_SUCCINT (2048) = 2309 -->;
    put ' <Flags>2309</Flags>';
    put '<Options>';
    put '    <Templates>';
    put '      <PhysicalTable/>';
    put '        <SASLibrary Engine="" Libref=""/>';
    put '    </Templates>';      
    put ' </Options>';
    put '</GetMetadataObjects>';
run;


* use a temporary fileref to hold the response;
filename response TEMP; *"%sysfunc(getoption(work))/response.xml";

proc metadata in=request out=response verbose;
run;

* release the temporary request;
filename request;

filename mapa temp;

data _null_;
    file mapa;
    put '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>';
    put '<!-- ############################################################ -->';
    put '<!-- 2014-02-05T15:41:54 -->';
    put '<!-- SAS XML Libname Engine Map -->';
    put '<!-- Generated by XML Mapper, 903200.3.0.20120523190000_v930m2 -->';
    put '<!-- ############################################################ -->';
    put '<SXLEMAP name="AUTO_GEN" version="2.1">';

    put '    <NAMESPACES count="0"/>';

    put '    <!-- ############################################################ -->';
    put '    <TABLE description="SASLibrary" name="SASLibrary">';
    put '        <TABLE-PATH syntax="XPath">/GetMetadataObjects/Objects/PhysicalTable/TablePackage/SASLibrary</TABLE-PATH>';

    put '        <COLUMN name="LibId">';
    put '            <PATH syntax="XPath">/GetMetadataObjects/Objects/PhysicalTable/TablePackage/SASLibrary/@Id</PATH>';
    put '            <TYPE>character</TYPE>';
    put '            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>';
    put '            <LENGTH>17</LENGTH>';
    put '        </COLUMN>';

    put '        <COLUMN name="Engine">';
    put '            <PATH syntax="XPath">/GetMetadataObjects/Objects/PhysicalTable/TablePackage/SASLibrary/@Engine</PATH>';
    put '            <TYPE>character</TYPE>';
    put '            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>';
    put '            <LENGTH>4</LENGTH>';
    put '        </COLUMN>';

    put '        <COLUMN name="Libref">';
    put '            <PATH syntax="XPath">/GetMetadataObjects/Objects/PhysicalTable/TablePackage/SASLibrary/@Libref</PATH>';
    put '            <TYPE>character</TYPE>';
    put '            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>';
    put '            <LENGTH>8</LENGTH>';
    put '        </COLUMN>';

    put '        <COLUMN name="TabID" retain="YES">';
    put '            <PATH syntax="XPath">/GetMetadataObjects/Objects/PhysicalTable/@Id</PATH>';
    put '            <TYPE>character</TYPE>';
    put '            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>';
    put '            <LENGTH>17</LENGTH>';
    put '        </COLUMN>';

    put '        <COLUMN name="Name_Table" retain="YES">';
    put '            <PATH syntax="XPath">/GetMetadataObjects/Objects/PhysicalTable/@Name</PATH>';
    put '            <TYPE>character</TYPE>';
    put '            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>';
    put '            <LENGTH>32</LENGTH>';
    put '        </COLUMN>';

    put '        <COLUMN name="SASTableName" retain="YES">';
    put '            <PATH syntax="XPath">/GetMetadataObjects/Objects/PhysicalTable/@SASTableName</PATH>';
    put '            <TYPE>character</TYPE>';
    put '            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>';
    put '            <LENGTH>32</LENGTH>';
    put '        </COLUMN>';

    put '        <COLUMN name="TableName" retain="YES">';
    put '            <PATH syntax="XPath">/GetMetadataObjects/Objects/PhysicalTable/@TableName</PATH>';
    put '            <TYPE>character</TYPE>';
    put '            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>';
    put '            <LENGTH>32</LENGTH>';
    put '        </COLUMN>';

    put '    </TABLE>';

    put '</SXLEMAP>';
run;


libname fim xmlv2 xmlfileref=response xmlmap=MAPA access=READONLY;

/*
 *  Local Extraction
 */

DATA SASLibrary; SET fim.SASLibrary; run;

* release the temporary file and libname;
filename response clear;
libname fim clear;
```

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. We have SAS 9.2 at my company and xmlv2 is in 9.3 I tried to use the XML92 instead but then I get Error message that the xmlmap is not properly formed. Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the reply but I only noticed you question today. 
These errors are usually due to a change on the datatype of the xmlmap column definition (the one presented above was generated automatically by the “SAS XML mapper” and because it worked I didn’t pay too much attention to the options on each of the definitions).
What I would suggest is for you to debug the code by commenting and uncommenting the put statements that are writing each column of the xmlmap.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This only brings back tables registered in libraries that use the BASE engine.  It won't bring back tables in other library engine types, eg ODBC or OLEDB.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else if type='Directory' then do;` line was outside of the necessary `do; end;` group.

Other than that, your code runs fine! See below.

```
data meta_libraries;
  length uri serveruri conn_uri domainuri libname ServerContext AuthDomain path_schema
         usingpkguri type tableuri coluri $256 id $17
         desc $200 libref engine $8 isDBMS $1 table colname coltype collen $32;
  keep libname desc libref engine ServerContext path_schema AuthDomain table colname
      coltype collen IsPreassigned IsDBMSLibname id;
  nobj=.;
  n=1;
  uri='';
  serveruri='';
  conn_uri='';
  domainuri='';

         /***Determine how many libraries there are***/
  nobj=metadata_getnobj("omsobj:SASLibrary?@Id contains '.'",n,uri);
         /***Retrieve the attributes for all libraries, if there are any***/
  if n>0 then do n=1 to nobj;
    libname='';
    ServerContext='';
    AuthDomain='';
    desc='';
    libref='';
    engine='';
    isDBMS='';
    IsPreassigned='';
    IsDBMSLibname='';
    path_schema='';
    usingpkguri='';
    type='';
    id='';
    nobj=metadata_getnobj("omsobj:SASLibrary?@Id contains '.'",n,uri);
    rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "Name", libname);
    rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "Desc", desc);
    rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "Libref", libref);
    rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "Engine", engine);
    rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "IsDBMSLibname", isDBMS);
    rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "IsDBMSLibname", IsDBMSLibname); 
    rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "IsPreassigned", IsPreassigned); 
    rc= metadata_getattr(uri, "Id", Id);

    /*** Get associated ServerContext ***/
    i=1;
    rc= metadata_getnasn(uri, "DeployedComponents", i, serveruri);
    if rc > 0 then rc2= metadata_getattr(serveruri, "Name", ServerContext);
    else ServerContext='';

    /*** If the library is a DBMS library, get the Authentication Domain
         associated with the DBMS connection credentials ***/
    if isDBMS="1" then do;
      i=1; 
      rc= metadata_getnasn(uri, "LibraryConnection", i, conn_uri);
      if rc > 0 then do;
        rc2= metadata_getnasn(conn_uri, "Domain", i, domainuri);
        if rc2 > 0 then rc3= metadata_getattr(domainuri, "Name", AuthDomain);
      end;
    end;

    /*** Get the path/database schema for this library ***/
    rc=metadata_getnasn(uri, "UsingPackages", 1, usingpkguri);
    if rc>0 then do;
      rc=metadata_resolve(usingpkguri,type,id);  
      if type='Directory' then 
        rc=metadata_getattr(usingpkguri, "DirectoryName", path_schema);
      else if type='DatabaseSchema' then 
        rc=metadata_getattr(usingpkguri, "Name", path_schema);
      else path_schema="unknown";
    end;

    /*** Get the tables associated with this library ***/
    /*** If DBMS, tables are associated with DatabaseSchema ***/
    if type='DatabaseSchema' then do;
      t=1;
      ntab=metadata_getnasn(usingpkguri, "Tables", t, tableuri);
      if ntab>0 then do t=1 to ntab;
        tableuri='';
        table='';
        ntab=metadata_getnasn(usingpkguri, "Tables", t, tableuri);
        tabrc= metadata_getattr(tableuri, "Name", table);
        output;
      end;
      else do;
        put 'Library ' libname ' has no tables registered';
        output;
      end;
    end;
    else if type='Directory' then do;
      t=1;
      ntab=metadata_getnasn(uri, "Tables", t, tableuri);
      if ntab>0 then do t=1 to ntab;
        tableuri='';
        table='';
        ntab=metadata_getnasn(uri, "Tables", t, tableuri);
        tabrc= metadata_getattr(tableuri, "Name", table);
        output;  
      end;
      else put 'Library ' libname ' has no tables registered'; 
    end;
  end;
  /***If there aren't any libraries, write a message to the log***/
  else put 'There are no libraries defined in this metadata repository.'; 
 run;

 proc sort; by libref table;run;
```